# Django Rest Aut - User registration

Tags: django, django-rest-auth

I´m using Django Rest Auth on Django 1.9 to register new users on system. And I need to execute some extra code in this process to save extra data on another tables.

Anybody knows the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Write **CustomRegisterSerializer** and add it to **settings.py** file.

```
    REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
        "REGISTER_SERIALIZER":"common_app.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer"
    }
```

Write **save()** method of newly created serializer and put **some extra executable code**.
If your user model have extra fields, you can write your **validate_field** methods.

For reference you can check **rest_auth RegistrationSerializer** here https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/registration/serializers.py

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with @ashish2py 's [reply above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36619378/454023):

However, want to add an example for custom serializer's save method for other's references.

**Steps:**

1. In settings.py file add below line. (assuming your app name is "common_app")

   ```
   REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
       "REGISTER_SERIALIZER":"common_app.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer"
   }
   ```
2. In common_app/serializer.py file add CustomRegisterSerializer class as below (which override save method).

   ```
   class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
     def save(self, request):
       user = super(CustomRegisterSerializer, self).save(request)
       logger.debug("[GroupProfile-Manager] Manager user registration #{}: {}".format(user.id, user.email))


       ### YOUR CUSTOM LOGIC GOES HERE ###

       group_prof_obj.join(user=user, role='manager')

       return user
   ```